# Is physics semantically deterministic?

Tags: logic, semantics

[image]

The Philosophy of Mathematics Today, By Matthias Schirn, p518

Is physics today about a "single object"? Or is it "indeterministic"?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Semantic determinacy is a property of languages/logics. Are you asking if the appropriate logic for physics would be semantically deterministic? If that is the question, I recommend looking into ["Quantum Logic"](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-quantlog/).

Comment: hi @Dennis it doesn't bode well that you don't understand. i am just asking if physical theories "have just one referent"?

Comment: it's a clumsy question, let me try to rephrase it

Comment: Ok, that makes me think that your question might be after something else. Talk of it being about a "single object" makes me think the question is about whether the singular terms of a physical theory have determinate reference -- or whether they might be ambiguous or otherwise referentially defective. If that's what you're after then the literature on ["underdetermination"](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-underdetermination/) might be of interest to you.

Comment: That's the general phenomena in theory choice where the choice of theory -- including the referents of the singular terms -- is not fully determined by the evidence. Some folks, e.g., the [constructive empiricists](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/constructive-empiricism/), think that we cannot know what our "theoretical terms" (or terms for "unobservables") refer to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most popular opinion right now is that physics is deterministic, simply because that assumption has lead to great success.  We don't know whether it is actually true or not, but we do often assume it.

However, in all real world cases, we do not have perfect information about the system.  Thus real world physics' predictive power is less than perfect, even if the underlying theories were perfect.  This would suggest that, in real life situations, it is effective to treat physics as a nondeterministic process.

Comment: in what way does it "suggest" that? i take it you mean "real world" to mean physics as it currently is?

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN It suggests it because I was avoiding use of a stronger word to draw the conclusion.  If the world is indeed nondeterminstic, then it is naturally would be effective to treat it as nondeterministic.  If, however, the world was deterministic, then it would still be effective to treat it as nondeterministic because we never know *all* of the information about a system.  It is reasonable to treat unknown values as nondeterministic until, through some method, you determine their value.

Comment: ok, i like your answer, and will accept it, but would really like some elaboration on exactly it is "reasonable" !

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN That might be a good subject for a chat room discussion.  It is far too in depth to do in comments because it scrapes the deepest versions of the meaning of "does science work?"  The particular answers to those questions that you hold would change the approach I would take for discussing "reasonable."

Answer (score 1):

> These structures form a natural generalization of ordinary multi-valued matrices, in which the truth-value of a complex formula can be chosen non-deterministically out of some non-empty set of options.

The projection postulate in the standard presentaton of quantum mechanics declare that the value of an observable is 'chosen non-deterministically' out of the 'non-empty' spectrum of the the operator representing the observable.

However it uses ordinary linear algebra, so just the usual matrices (once a basis is chosen) and not a generalisation thereof; not that some other mechanism might not prove useful in the future; for example there is Coeckes Categorical QM.